# Get the html or total body height using only javascript

Tags: javascript

On a project where I'm only able to use javascript (not Jquery), I need to get the html height or the body height in total.

I already tried this:

**Javascript**

```
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;

alert(x);
// display the windows size not the total size of the page
```

Otherwise, I found this function.

```
   function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight,
        D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
}

alert( getDocHeight() );
```

but, it doesn't work, I get this error: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null

Any help will be appreciated

Currently, I'm using chrome on a mac, but I would like to make it work on all browsers

Comment: What browser does it not work in?

Comment: What browser are you using this in? Working fine in Chrome.

Comment: I'm using chrome, but I would like to make it work across all browsers

Comment: So if you go here: http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/9pf3N/ - You don't get an alert?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/9pf3N/ here I'm getting the message, not on my project

Comment: Look at jQuery's height() and width() functions. They should contain code that you are looking for.